# spring boot rsocket with "message was successfully sent"

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, rsocket

I have a client that needs to receive an Exception from the server

client:

```
rSocketRequester
    .route("v1.data")
    .data(data)
    .sendAndAwait()
```

server:

```
return Mono.error(RuntimeException("test excep"))
```

In docs say: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html#rsocket-requester-requests "For Fire-and-Forget use the send() method that returns Mono. Note that the Mono indicates only that the message was successfully sent, and not that it was handled."

How do i get message was complete or the exception data?

Answer (score 0):

Switch to a Request-Response operation instead of Fire-and-Forget, you may want to assume the result is a lightweight result object, or empty byte.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/3ed8813bbfc1678de73529a882ce535e2636519c/src/docs/asciidoc/rsocket.adoc

Java

```
Mono<AirportLocation> location = requester.route("find.radar.EWR"))
    .retrieveMono(AirportLocation.class);
```

Kotlin

```
import org.springframework.messaging.rsocket.retrieveAndAwait

val location = requester.route("find.radar.EWR")
    .retrieveAndAwait<AirportLocation>()
```

Comment: I thought about it but it is like HTTP status code. And Fire-and-Forget can return Mono<Void>. I think need to configure the client correctly and that's all.

Comment: Yes, but you won't find out about remote failure. Just that client sent request.